# Declaring a variable via a Zapier input in Python

Tags: python, zapier

I'm trying to do a simple declaration of an inputted variable to an integer, but am receiving an error:

Bargle. We hit an error creating a run python. :-( Error: 
Your code had an error! Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/tmpXq4aAP/usercode.py", line 7, in the_function num = int(input['managers']) KeyError: 'num'

The following is the code i'm using:

```
num = int(input['num'])

if num >= 100 :
  big_num = true
else:
  big_num = false

return {'big_num': big_num}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Zapier, the code:

`input['varname']`

refers to the variable that is passed in the "Code by Zapier" Action.

The error you are getting sounds to me like you have not defined the `num` variable prior to your code.

Also, `True` and `False` need to be capitalized.

Otherwise, see below, this setup works...

[image]

```
num = int(input['num'])

if num >= 100 :
  big_num = True
else:
  big_num = False

return {'big_num': big_num}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error is right here:

```
num = int(input['num'])
```

Change those square brackets for round brackets:

```
num = int(input('num'))
```

If you are on Python 2 you should use `raw_input`

```
num = int(raw_input('num'))
```

Comment: New error:
Your code had an error! Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/tmpMfNcV0/usercode.py", line 7, in the_function num = int(input('num')) TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: What version of Python are you using and what what are you inputting exactly

Comment: According to Zapier, the environment is vanilla Python 2.7.10. It's basically a code transformation of data en route to another app via a source app. See their page here - https://zapier.com/help/code-python/

Comment: @csakon You should use raw_input if you are using Python 2. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hye @idjaw, the input variable in Zapier is overridden with a dictionary of inputs reflecting values from the previous step. This answer outlines it well enough https://stackoverflow.com/a/36001218/4188138

Comment: @SamKamensky Thanks for the heads up on this. I'll have to revisit this answer shortly. Overriding Python built-ins is such a terrible idea! I really hope they change (or have changed) this.

Comment: They've since added another variable called input_data to ease confusion, but they still override the built-in input function for backwards compatibility :P. Search for "input" on this web page https://zapier.com/help/code-python/

Answer (score 1):

Many of these answers reference the `input()` built in - we override that in Code by Zapier (since it literally makes zero sense to have user input on an automated script). In it's place is a dictionary defined by some fields above.

Definitely confusing for folks unfamiliar with the context of Zapier - we'll look into renaming it and just nulling the `input` build.

Answer (score 0):

Input is a kernel method and it can't be subscriptable , there is an syntax error change the code to like this.

```
num = int(input('num'))
```

Comment: New error:
Your code had an error! Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/tmpMfNcV0/usercode.py", line 7, in the_function num = int(input('num')) TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Which version of python you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Within Zapier, the proper way to convert Input Data (every input into a Code Step is a String) to Integers is as follows:

```
num = int(input.get('num'))
```

or

```
num = int(input['num'])
```

If the number comes attached with a decimal, strip the unwanted characters from the String before converting to an Integer. For a number like 80.0 this would look like:

```
num = int(input['num'][:-2])
```